# link between two elements in the same page doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, anchor, href

so I'm using this code in order to have a smooth transition between pages

```
window.transitionToPage = function(href) {
    document.querySelector('body').style.opacity = 0
    setTimeout(function() { 
        window.location.href = href
    }, 500)
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
    document.querySelector('body').style.opacity = 1
});

const swup = new Swup();
```

In the "projects section" the user cannot scroll using the scrollbar, he can only scroll vertically by clicking a button (actually the body has the *overflow-y: hidden* attribute).

Everything works fine untill the code above is linked into the project section (both if the code is in an external file or between script tags in the html file).

I have two scenarios:

1. transition between pages works fine but buttons in the projects sections don't work (you can click them but nothing happens);
2. user can scroll by clicking buttons but smooth transitions betwwn pages doesn't work (animation looks hella weird).

thanks in advice

Comment: Can you set up some kind of reproducible example either here or on stackblitz or the like?

Comment: i have a couple of a tags like this <a class="indicator up" id="indicatorUp1" href="#projectSection1">&#8593</a> all linked togheter. If the code above is linked into the html page, the hyperlink doesn't work

Comment: @Kinglish excuse me, did you want me to link all my code?